# How to make date change dynamically in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

```
Orders
Order-id, Order_Date, Customer_id, Payment_id, Total_price

Order2Product
Product_id, Order_id, Quantity
```

What I want is to extract the sales information regarding the number of products sold in a day, week and month

I applied the following query to get the number of products sold within a given date range.

```
select count(quantity)
from orders o,order2product op,product p
where o.order_id = op.order_id AND op.product_id = p.product_id AND   Order_Date BETWEEN "2015-03-05" AND "2015-03-19";
```

My questions are:

1. How can I make the date change dynamically so that every time, the owner of the website wants to know the sales information made on that respective day, week and date
2. How to get the total money they made by selling the products on that respective day, week and month.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(quantity)
from orders o,order2product op,product p
where o.order_id = op.order_id 
AND op.product_id = p.product_id 
AND Order_Date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() - 1 WEEK;
```

This should do the trick on your first question I believe.
Please read http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp

Comment: 1 Week should be within quotes '1 Week'. By Week we mean to return the week number but the 1 what does that suggest?. Is it like the current time and date - (1 week before the current time and date). And if it was month it would be current time and date - (1 month before the current time and date) ?

Comment: why doesn't something like this work select sum(Quantity)
from orders o,order2product k,product p
were o.order_id = k.order_id AND k.product_id = p.product_id 
AND Order_date < (select DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))